# How can I run jest on a React project where the babel config file is in a subfolder instead of root?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, babeljs

I'm in a project where the babel config is in a subfolder:

```
config
|- babel.json
package.json
```

When I run jest it breaks

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

[...]
```

If I move `babel.json` to the root folder as `.babelrc` then all tests work.

Can I tell jest to look for a specific babel config file or does it need to be in the root?